# How to present Users Option in Algorithm or Pseudo Code

Tags: algorithm, user-input, pseudocode, multiple-choice

I have a software that asks user to choose different options from 3 sets of parameters before running the program with those inputs. However, I don't know how to show that in an algorithm or a Pseudo code in a correct way.
Example

```
step 1: for X, choose from 5-10-15-20 
step 2: for Y, choose between a,b,c,d
step 3: for Z, choose from 10 to 20
step 4: calculate M=X+2Z
step 5: print row M of Y
```

Thanx for the help in advance

Comment: how about in algorithms? how user choice or input is presented?

Comment: among others, the suitability of a mode of presentation depends on your audience and the purpose. in general, i think, its usually helpful to state the purpose of a code portion first and to give a high-level summary of what is done for what reason. technicalities like the precise computation involved is often less relevant. your mileage may vary, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no 'correct' ways in pseudo-code. You can really just do whatever you want, the only *preference* is that all terms and syntax used should be clearly understandable, thus, for syntax, it should be commonly used elsewhere to indicate the desired operation.

One option comes to mind: `"Let X = a user-picked value from one of these: 5, 10, 15"`

More brief: `"Let the user pick X ∈ {5, 10, 15}"`

Obviously if your algorithm fundamentally includes getting input from the user, this is not possible, but if the user input can be separated from your algorithm without changing anything, I would think a better way would be to say the value is given:

```
"Given X ∈ {5, 10, 15}"
```

It would make sense to me that all `"Given"`'s should be at the start of the algorithm. If you want to get something from the user in the middle of an algorithm, saying `"Let the user pick..."` as above would make more sense.

"In algorithms" doesn't really make sense. One can describe an algorithm in natural language (words / sentences / paragraphs), pseudo-code or in code in a specific language. And usually the user input is outside of the algorithm. For example, one would not say to get a list of values from the user for a sorting algorithm, one would start with "Given a list of values".